# openFileDialog, saveFileDialog

Tags: c#, .net

Если не трудно то можно пошагово объяснить работу с тем и другим объектом? Или хорошую ссылку.

Answer (score 7):

Пример коректного использования...

```
using (var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Comma Separated Value(*.csv) | *.csv";
    //openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "<путь к папке>";//если нужно

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        OpenCsvFile(openFileDialog.FileName);
    }
}
```

saveFileDialog используется по аналогии с даным кодом.

Сам компонент на форму добавлять не нужно. Убивать тоже, он сам диспоузнется по окончанию using конструкции.

Answer (score 3):

Все просто. Если диалог не добавлен как компонент формы, то создаем его.

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
```

Задаем параметры:

1) Типы файлов

```
openFileDialog.Filter = "Файлы Excel (*.xls; *.xlsx) | *.xls; *.xlsx";
```

2) Можно задать начальную директорию:

```
openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "<путь к папке>";
```

Остальные параметры можно посмотреть на MSDN, там они все описаны. И наконец вызываем его:

```
openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
```

Функция ShowDialog() вернет значение из перечисления System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult, по которому можно определить что нажал пользователь. Имя файла с полным путем до него:

```
openFileDialog.FileName;
```

Для диалога SaveFileDialog все анологично.

Comment: Только лучше ещё всю работу с диалоговыми окнами заворачивать в конструкцию `using`, чтобы сразу же после закрытия освобождать ресурсы, занятые ими:

    using (var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        ...
    }

Answer (score 1):

Вы сами поленились "погуглить" или вам не подходит информация с мсдн? Если не искали, то вот:

[OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx)

[SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx)

Comment: Искал, но не то. Эти ссылки я сам впервую очередь нашёл, но там опять как-то через... Если можно то что-то получше.

Comment: Что значит получше? Чем вас не устраивают примеры по етим ссылкам? Что вам конкретно не понятно или в чем проблема? И что именно вы считаете в данных примерах через "..."?