# Редактор текста

Tags: c#

Приветствую! Пишу простой редактор на C#, есть компонент `richTextbox1`, там хранится, скажем, текст файла txt. Как это сделать?

Т.е. как вызвать диалоговое окно файлов, выбрать файл и что бы его содержимое оказалось в `richTextbox1`, сохранить все это дело? И как закрыть программу по нажатию кнопки?

Подскажите хотя бы какие компоненты нужны, а дальше я в мануал и буду их курить.

Answer (score 1):

[Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/87480/openfiledialog-savefiledialog?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=87628#87628) как работать с диалогами открытия и сохранения. А потом берешь любой ридер, например StreamReader и счиытваешь как угодно (по строчкам или целиком)

Answer (score 1):

1. Открыть : [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx)
2. Читаешь открытый файл, текст файла присваиваешь свойству Text в richTextBox
3. Сохраняешь [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx)